# PHP Out of Memory - Clear Memory?

Tags: php, magento, out-of-memory

We just a complaint from a client for which we did a magento implemantion saying his email form didn't work.

Turns out this was because it was out of memory.

Now i've been reading a lot about this and everything says i need to **up my memory limit**. We have already asked the **hosting company** for other issues to do this but they **can't**. Now since this installation has been working fine for a year without any changes we don't want to switch hosts.

**Is there any way we can clear the memory so it runs again??**

Comment: No. The memory limit is set by your host. You don't "clear" it. Every time your site runs it fills up the memory. That's your issue. You need to up the limit either by paying more or moving host if they won't do it for free. Or fix whatever is hogging your memory if some terrible recursion is going on.

Comment: Running baby 32M or 64M memory_limit on shared hosting does this. You have to allow enough memory to run scripts. PHP limits the size to prevent crashing the system. Magento memory requirements start at 256M. This is actually a Web Server High-School Server Admin question for PHP applications. It doesn't even rate a College 101 course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the memory available to PHP using `php_value memory_limit` in `.htaccess`. However it sounds like you're on shared hosting which isn't powerful enough for what you're trying to do. It's likely that you'll not be able to up the memory limit using `.htaccess` too if this is the case.

It's probably time to upgrade your hosting if you're running into issues like this.

Comment: Typical Shared Hosting Heartburn. It ran for a year while the site was small and taking few orders. Now that we're actually starting to do business, Whoops, we've just found out that Magento Expects resources and will punish you by cutting off your income... DYH...